# How to remove blank columns from excel using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I wanted to remove unwanted columns towards the last or any blank columns without header in between columns, then remove formatting from excel worksheet from each rows and column using EPPlus.

Please find the sample progress.

```
public static class EpPlusExtension
{
    public static string[] GetHeaderColumns(this ExcelWorksheet sheet)
    {
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var firstRowCell in sheet.Cells[sheet.Dimension.Start.Row, sheet.Dimension.Start.Column, 1, sheet.Dimension.End.Column])
            columnNames.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
        return columnNames.ToArray();
    }

    public static ExcelWorksheet RemoveCellFormatter(this ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic cellValue = null;
            int lastColumnWithHeaderIndex = worksheet.GetHeaderColumns().Count();
                for (int i = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row; i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= lastColumnWithHeaderIndex; j++)
                    {
                        if (worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null)
                        {
                            cellValue = worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value;
                            worksheet.Cells[i, j].Clear();
                            worksheet.Cells[i, j].Value = cellValue;
                            cellValue = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            return worksheet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error Message: Exception While clearing formatting from worksheet. |Exception: {ex.Message}");
            return worksheet;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample code handles the last unwanted columns:
[image]

How to handle also null columns in-between?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a loop that checks all the headers `for (int i = 1; i <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; i++)` and if not delete the column `worksheet.DeleteColumn(i);`

Comment: it removes column even if there is header.It need to retain those columns with header .

Answer (score 0):

I am not an EPPlus expert and was unable to find a method that would remove “empty” columns. However, as VDWWD notes, it should not be difficult to loop through the rows of a column and check to see if all the cells in that column are `null` and if so, then remove that column.

Obviously, if there are many rows, then this may not be the best approach. If there are many rows and columns, there is possibly another option, however, in this case, I will assume the execution time is acceptable. In my tests, the worksheet contained 735 rows and 9 columns with two (2) empty columns and it took less than a second.

Given this, a simple solution is to loop through the columns. In each column iteration, loop through all the rows. We will use two variables: a `bool` `valueFound` and set it to `false`. This will be used to indicate if we found a non null value in a cell. And a `List<int>` `emptyColIndexes` is a list of `ints` to hold the indexes of the columns that are "empty" in the worksheet.

> NOTE: it should be obvious that we DO NOT want to “delete” the empty
> column as soon as we find one. We only want to store its index and
> delete the columns later. The reason for this… is… deleting the column
> while “looping” through the columns will obviously cause problems.
> Therefore, we only want to get a list of the indexes of the “empty”
> columns.

When looping through the rows of a column, IF we find a value that is NOT `null`, then we set `valueFound` to `true` and exit the rows loop using a `break` command. If we loop through all the rows in a column and exit the loop, we will check the `valueFound` variable, IF it is `false`, then this would mean all the row values in that column are `null`, then we add that columns index to the `emptyColIndexes` list.

Lastly, after collecting all the “empty” column indexes, we loop through the indexes and delete the columns.

> NOTE: this loop needs to start from the “last” column index and move
> to the first. This should be obvious being that if we delete a column
> on the left of another column in the list, then the indexes will get
> messed up. Basically, we want to delete the columns from the right to
> left. Therefore, the loop starts at the last index and goes to the
> first index.

In addition, and it is not important, however, it appears that returning the worksheet in the `RemoveCellFormatter` is unnecessary.

Below is the code that demonstrates what is described above.

```
public static void RemoveEmptyColumns(ExcelWorksheet worksheet) {
  try {
    List<int> emptyColIndexes = new List<int>();
    bool valueFound;
    for (int curCol = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Column; curCol <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column; curCol++) {
      valueFound = false;
      for (int curRow = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row; curRow <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; curRow++) {
        if (worksheet.Cells[curRow, curCol].Value != null) {
          valueFound = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!valueFound) {
        emptyColIndexes.Add(curCol);
      }
    }
    if (emptyColIndexes.Count > 0) {
      for (int i = emptyColIndexes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        worksheet.DeleteColumn(emptyColIndexes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error Message: Exception while removing empty columns from worksheet. " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```